# How to create action bar tab on xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And into MainActivity.cs

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            //Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            // button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };

            // enable navigation mode to support tab layout
            this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

            //adding genres tab
            AddTab("Genres", new GenresFragment());
            //adding music tab
            AddTab("Music", new MusicFragment());
            //
        }

        /*
         tabText:title to be displayed in tab
         iconResourceId: image/source id
         fragment:fragment reference
         */

        void AddTab(string tabText, Fragment fragment)
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetText(tabText);
            // if using icon-> tab.SetIcon(iconResourceId)

            //must set event handler for replacing tabs tab

            tab.TabReselected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
              {
                  e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
              };
            this.ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
        }
```

The first, I got a problem that is **Resource.Id.fragmentContainer does not contain definition for fragmentContainer. **.

I'm new developer on xamarin(visual studio 2015). So please everyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Just above SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);, add the following code.

```
ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
```

Step 2 : Add these code in OnCreate Method

```
ActionBar.Tab tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab.SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.tab1_text));
tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab1_icon);
tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
                       // Do something when tab is selected
                   }
ActionBar.AddTab(tab);

tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab.SetText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.tab2_text));
tab.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.tab2_icon);
tab.TabSelected += (sender, args) => {
                       // Do something when tab is selected
                   }
ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
```

If you need to support older device, please include AppCompat library and inherit you Activity class from ActionBarActivity.

Comment: The tabs I create are not taking up the entire width available to them. How can I stretch them so that no empty space is left on the sides?